# Wso2carbon logs 2 logstash using tcp input plugin, without filebeat

Tags: logstash, wso2, elastic-stack

I'm trying to transfer wso2carbon logs to elk using tcp input plugin

my config for wso2  log4jproperties file.

```
#TCP logger pattern log4j.appender.tcp=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.tcp.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB log4j.appender.tcp.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m {%c}%n log4j.appender.tcp.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S] log4j.appender.tcp.Port=6000 log4j.appender.tcp.RemoteHost=localhost log4j.appender.tcp.ReconnectionDelay=10000 log4j.appender.tcp.threshold=DEBUG log4j.appender.tcp.Application=wso2carbon
```

Config for logstash.conf

```
input {     tcp {       mode => server      port => 6000        add_field =>            type
=> "wso2carbon"
        }   } }
```

I'm successfully getting messages from wso2carbon.  but the message like encrypted format. like below.

```
{
       "message" => "threadNameq\\u0000~\\u0000\\u0001L\\u0000\\rthrowableInfot\\u0000+Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation;xp\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0001c\\xD9\\xC9\\xF3,t\\u0000Forg.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorkerpsr\\u0000\\u0013java.util.Hashtable\\u0013\\xBB\\u000F%!J\\xE4\\xB8\\u0003\\u0000\\u0002F\\u0000",
          "host" => "127.0.0.1",
      "@version" => "1",
          "port" => 59581,
          "type" => "wso2carbon",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-06-07T10:28:01.179Z,
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ] }
```

please let me know how to decrypt this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't [specify the codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html#plugins-inputs-tcp-codec) to be used to decode your message when received, codecs are a convenient method for decoding your data before it enters the input, without needing a separate filter in your Logstash pipeline.

add this in your input under `mode => server` ,

```
codec => json
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Het Sufiyan, Tried with codec json also. but no luck

Comment: Hi Sufiyan ghori,  

 input {
 tcp {
  mode => server
  port => 6000
  add_field => {
   type => "wso2carbon"
        }
  codec => json {
   charset => "UTF-8"
  }
 }